# 405 Cilent error: python-social-auth Instagram authentication

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I'm using `python-social-auth` in a `django-1.8` application.

When I'm trying to authenticate user with Instagram, getting 405 client error.

```
**HTTPError at /complete/instagram/**

405 Client Error: METHOD NOT ALLOWED

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/complete/instagram/?redirect_state=UwLzMumZrmutkodL8IVxpBSaqKCkR5cM&code=91ca51afffa8485580b91d756edb4b20&state=UwLzMumZrmutkodL8IVxpBSaqKCkR5cM

Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: HTTPError
Exception Value: 405 Client Error: METHOD NOT ALLOWED

Exception Location: /app/portal/authexception.py in process_exception, line 14

Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python

Python Version: 2.7.11
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.7.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python27.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
]

Server time:    Tue, 15 Dec 2015 08:43:36 +0000
```

My same code was working last week, but since 3-4 days, I'm getting same error.

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, i am not able to upload screenshot, in place of it I have paste the error message here

Comment: Could it be https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/pull/797 ? If that's the case, then you might need to either monkeypatch `InstagramOAuth2`, or subclass it in your app, and redefine the endpoint URLs, at least until a new version of python-social-auth gets released.